# Candidate key = Key = Minimal Superkey?

Tags: schema, primary-key, relational-theory

I got a little confused by all these keys. As I understand

```
A key of a relational schema = 
The minimal subset of a superkey that is still a key = 
A candidate key
```

Is this correct or not?

Answer (score 4):

Just found out very neat explanation:

**superkey**: a set of attributes which will uniquely identify each tuple in a relation

**candidate key**: a minimal superkey

**primary key**: a chosen candidate key

**secondary key**: all the rest of candiate keys

**prime attribute**: an attribute that is a part of a candidate key (key column)

**nonprime attribute**: a nonkey column